# Expected ')' before ';' token error?

Tags: iphone, token

I am creating an Iphone app, and It works by an NSTimer that calls the -(void)gameLoop every sixtieth of a second. here is the gameLoop

```
-(void)gameLoop {

 paratrooperTimer += 1;

if (gameState == KGameStateBegin) {
    BtnStart.hidden = 0;
    BtnResume.hidden = 1;
    BtnPause.hidden = 1;
} 
else if (gameState == KGameStateRunning) {

    BtnStart.hidden = 1;
    BtnPause.hidden = 0;

    [self playGameLoop];
}
else if (gameState == KGameStatePaused) {

    BtnResume.hidden = 0;
    BtnPause.hidden = 1;
}
else if (gameState == KGameStateGameOver) {

    [self endGame];
}
else if (paratrooperTimer == 120) {

    (paratrooperTimer = 0);
    [self spawnParatrooper];

}



}
```

I get the error "Expected ')' before ';' token" in every if statement and in the ParatrooperTimer+=1 line.

GameState is and Integer, and so are all of the KGameState... .
Please Help me!
Thanks a bunch

Comment: The code you've submitted here has imbalanced curly braces. Whether that's because your code is imbalanced or because of partial copy-and-paste is impossible for us to tell. For sure what you've put here is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't what your question is about, but you've raised a red flag for me that I've run into before and you would probably appreciate some advance warning about.

NSTimer fires at the end of the event loop. It's not a metronome--it gets called when it gets called, and it might not be regular at all. A long process that blocks the app will prevent an NSTimer from getting fired on time. Also an NSTimer has a max resolution of 50-100ms (per the docs). So in the BEST case, it'll fire 20 times a second, and you're trying to ask it for three times finer resolution than that.

For lower-resolution stuff, NSTimer is great, but to pulse as fast as you want it to, it probably doesn't work at all. But then, do you really need 60 frames/sec?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an unbalanced parenthesis somewhere above `- (void)gameLoop`, or maybe you left out the semicolon from method declaration `- (void)gameLoop;` in your .h file (but I think that would give you a different error message).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add (NSTimer *) aTimer to your function signature like this:

```
-(void)gameLoop :(NSTimer *) aTimer
```

and in the selector of `[NSTimer scheduleWithTimeInterval...` you should add a semicolon:

```
@selector(gameLoop:)
```

As for your function:

what is this line about in your last if statement and why do you need parenthesis there?

```
(paratrooperTimer = 0);
```

Probably this is the cause of the compiler error

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect either parenthesis typo or invalid timer signature.

Example for timer:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0   
                                              target:self   
                                            selector:@selector(timerHandler:) 
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
```

where `timerHandler` is defined as:

```
- (void)updateTimeView:(id)inTimer;
```

Anyway, why don't you use `switch-case` statement? With lots of `if` it can help maintain readbility of the code, so parenthesis typos can be found easier and faster. 
[Switch-case explanation](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Objective-C_switch_Statement)